# How to evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{x^2} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2} dt $?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to evaluate this limit:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{x^2} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2} \mathrm{d}t$$

This is what I've got so far: if we consider $\displaystyle F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2} \mathrm{d}t$, then using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we can rewrite the limit as:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{F(x)}{F'(x)}$

But how do I proceed from here? Or is there an easier way to go about this?

Comment: Your expression is $(\sqrt\pi/2)e^{x^2}$. Are you sure that's what you wish to ask about?

Comment: Check, that question may not have been written properly. Right now it is a trivial one as $e^{x^2}$ becomes $\infty$, when $n \to \infty}$ and the integral is finite any way. So the limit goes to $\infty$.

Comment: I guess it's $\displaystyle\color{red}{x}$ instead of $\displaystyle\color{red}{\infty}$ or $\displaystyle\color{red}{0}$ in the integral.

Comment: Maybe you mean $e^{-x^2}\int_0^x e^{t^2}dt$?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I've made the edits.

Comment: Still is trivial, you have (unbounded function) times (function tending to a constant).

Comment: @runway44: For your previous comment, it is $-t^2$ inside the integral and $x^2$ outside.

Comment: But then your question is trivial!

Comment: If it were $e^{x^2}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt$ it would be an interesting question.

Comment: [The limit tends to infinity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+e%5E%28x%5E2%29+*+%28integral+of+e%5E%28-t%5E2%29+from+t+%3D+0+to+x%29+as+x+to+infinity).

Comment: I understand it may be trivial, but could someone reason it out for me? So far, I see a product of two functions, one of which tends to $\infty$ and the other tends to a constant.  But the product rule for limits doesn't apply (since the limit of the left function $e^{x^2}$ doesn't exist). So how would one prove that it goes to $\infty$?

Comment: $f(x)$ tends to $+\infty$ iff it eventually gets bigger than any prescribed value without returning lower. Can you see why any positive multiple of $f(x)$ also satisfies that property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to show $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x^2}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt=\infty$.

Since $e^{x^2}$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$ are both positive non-decreasing functions, so is their product, so it is enough to show that for all large enough $X>0$, there exists an $x$ such that $\displaystyle e^{x^2}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt\ge X$.

Denote $\displaystyle c=\int_0^1e^{-x^2}dx>0$.

For $X>e^c$, let $x=\max\{\sqrt{\ln(X)-c},1\}$. Then $\displaystyle e^{x^2}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt\ge e^{\ln(X)-c}\int_0^1e^{-t^2}dt\ge X$.